# Core Data - Shared code called from NSManagedObjectContext peformBlock:

Tags: core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using `performBlock` on my `NSManagedObjectContexts` so that my changes happen on the right queue for the given context.  My question is - if I'm making a lot of changes and calling methods from within `performBlock` - is there an easy way to ensure that I use objects from the proper context.

Example:

I have an `activeAccount` iVar ( created on the Main Queue ) that is a `NSMangedObject` for the current account in the application.  I have some instance methods that use the `activeAccount` object to perform certain tasks - getting data, setting data.  So my question is if I am doing something on a background `NSManagedObjectContext` and I call one of these shared methods - is there a pattern I can use so that in these methods I know to either use the current `activeAccount` iVar or get a new one.  Also, if I needed to do something that requires a `NSManagedObjectContext` - how do I know which one to get/use.

One method I have for knowing which `NSManagedObjectContext` to use is I have a method that checks if it is running on the current thread - it then knows to return the main thread's context or the background thread's context.  Also, if I'm on the background thread, am I allowed to read the Object ID of the `activeAccount` that lives on the main thread so that I can get a copy of it on the background thread?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

Thread confinement can be a tricky proposition to maintain. The key thing you need to maintain is using objects in their proper MOC. As every managed object maintains a link to both its host MOC and its object ID, this is really easy to ensure. For example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *newMOC = NSManagedObjectContext.new;

newMOC.persistentStoreCoordinator = oldActiveAccount.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator;

ActiveAccount *newActiveAccount = [newMOC objectWithID: oldActiveAccount.objectID];
```

Now every instance you access from `newActiveAccount` is created in the `newMOC` and is, hence, thread confined to that MOC. `objectID`s are persistent. The `-persistentStoreCoordinator` is rarely, if ever, changed on the `mainMOC`. Hence, the above code is properly confined. There are issues with the above technique if the source MOC is transient. Hence, I cannot guarantee the above code works with respect to two background MOCs.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask first, why are you having so many contexts in use at the same time?

I use one for background operations and one for main thread. If I need to create another one for discardable changes, I'll just create it and pass it on, so now my self.managedObjectContext points to the draft context. I will never let my managed objects to live in a scope where they could access a multitude of contexts.

It is not entirely clear if you are writing for iOS or OSX, but with iOS for example:

If I need to push a new view controller into navigation stack I will initialize my destination view controller's managedObjectContext ivar as well as any NSManagedObject subclass instances. Since in -prepareForSegue: I know whether I'll create a draft context or just pass on my current one, I also know whether I need to initialize those managed object instances by referencing them by their IDs from newly created context or I can just pass them on.

Now inside my view controller I can take it for granted that my managed objects are always tied to the self.managedObjectContext.

Comment: I am developing for iOS.  I really only have two MOCs, one for the main thread and one to run in the background.  I guess my problem is that I have code that I'm trying to reuse so I have placed in into methods.  But I didn't want to say that method X could only be run in this ManagedObjectContext.  In one case I am creating a new relationship to account.  The object that contains this has an account iVar.  So I'm trying to decide if I can join to the iVar or if I have to create another account object for the background MOC. Maybe I need to limit each method to a given MOC.